# Mongoose indexes at both field and schema levels

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I understand that indexing can be a valuable tool for quickly retrieving data, if implemented properly. I would like to be able to scan my documents for a certain field value *or* a combination of field values.

There are two fields I would be indexing (category, tags). Category is a string and tags is an array. I need to be able to query for items in a specific category and/or items that contain a specific tag.

Here are three examples:

1. Show me all of the documents in the category: "cars"
2. Show me all of the documents that contain the tag: "electric"
3. Show me all of the documents in the "cars" category that contain the "electric" tag

Will a schema level index for both fields suffice for all three scenarios?

```
docSchema.index({category:1, tags:1});
```

Or do I also need to define them at the field level, to support the scenarios when I am only searching through a single field?

```
docSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    category: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    tags: {
        type: [String],
        index: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`docSchema.index({category:1, tags:1});` is a compound index.

This compound index supports the scenarios 1 and 3:

-> Show me all of the documents in the category: "cars"

-> Show me all of the documents in the "cars" category that contain the "electric" tag

To support scenario 2 you will need to define an **additional** single index on the `tag` field.
`docSchema.index({tags:1});`

A compound index supports queries that involve all fields in the compound index as well as queries that involve a **prefix** of the compound index. In this case your compound index supports queries involving both **categories and tags** as well as queries involving just **categories**.

To better understand the logic please take a look at the [Compound Indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/) articles on MongoDB documentation site. Pay special attention to the section that talks about **Prefixes**.

Answer (score 3):

You need an [single field index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-single/) on `category` and a [multikey index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/) on `tags`. You might be tempted to use a compound index instead of one of them. But it is not mandatory if you are using MongoDB >= 2.6, as it has a nice feature called [index intersection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/).

> 1. Show me all of the documents in the category: "cars"
> 2. Show me all of the documents that contain the tag: "electric"
> 3. Show me all of the documents in the "cars" category that contain the "electric" tag

(1) will use the index on `category` (incl. any index having `category` as a prefix)
(2) will use the index on `tags` (incl. any index having `tags` as a prefix)
(3) will use the  index on `tags` *or* the index on `category` *or* the *index intersection* of both of them (depending the choice of the query planner).

As a reference, there is a nice [discussion about index intersection in the MongoDB blog](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87790974798/efficient-indexing-in-mongodb-2-6). Worth reading the entire article. But to quote the conclusion, mostly comparing index intersection to compound indexes:

> To be clear, compound indexing will ALWAYS be more performant [than index intersection] IF you know what you are going to be querying on and can create one ahead of time. Furthermore, if your working set is entirely in memory, then you will not reap any of the benefits of Index Intersection as it is primarily based on reducing IO. But in a more ad-hoc case where one cannot predict the shape of the queries and the working set is much larger than available memory, index intersection will automatically take over and choose the most performant path.